# Reading a text file backwards in C

Tags: c, text, stream, standard-library

What's the best way to read a file backwards in C? I know at first you may be thinking that this is no use whatsoever, but most logs etc. append the most recent data at the end of the file. I want to read in text from the file backwards, buffering it into lines - that is

abc
def
ghi

should read **ghi**, **def**, **abc** in lines.

So far I have tried:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>

    void read_file(FILE *fileptr)
    {
        char currentchar = '\0';
        int size = 0;

        while( currentchar != '\n' )
        {
            currentchar = fgetc(fileptr); printf("%c\n", currentchar);
            fseek(fileptr, -2, SEEK_CUR);
            if( currentchar == '\n') { fseek(fileptr, -2, SEEK_CUR); break; }
            else size++;

        }
        char buffer[size]; fread(buffer, 1, size, fileptr);
        printf("Length: %d chars\n", size);
        printf("Buffer: %s\n", buffer);


    }


    int main(int argc, char *argv[])
    {
        if( argc < 2) { printf("Usage: backwards [filename]\n"); return 1; }

        FILE *fileptr = fopen(argv[1], "rb");
        if( fileptr == NULL ) { perror("Error:"); return 1; }

        fseek(fileptr, -1, SEEK_END); /* Seek to END of the file just before EOF */
        read_file(fileptr);


        return 0;


    }
```

In an attempt to simply read one line and buffer it. Sorry that my code is terrible, I am getting so very confused. I know that you would normally allocate memory for the whole file and then read in the data, but for large files that constantly change I thought it would be better to read directly (especially if I want to search for text in a file).

Thanks in advance

*** Sorry forgot to mention this will be used on Linux, so newlines are just NL without CR. ***

Comment: You could possibly [memory map the file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory-mapped_file), and use pointer arithmetic to "read" the file. Might be simpler than having to constantly jump around with the file pointer.

Comment: From the C standard: `A binary stream need not meaningfully support fseek calls with a whence value of SEEK_END.`

Comment: Probably you could log into DB instead of plain file?

Comment: Instead of reading the whole file at once, you could read it in large chunks, starting at the end.

Comment: @VaughnCato I believe the op is trying figure out HOW to do just that.

Comment: Is this something that needs to be able to read the file on-the-fly for display?  One way I could think to do this is to perform a NON-BUFFERED (meaning you dont allocate memory for the whole file) read using getline commands.  Then you hold a buffer of ONLY the char positions of each new line, then use those positions with the seek command to read backwards.

Comment: Alternatively you could use the file size to seek to the end of the file, then begin reading character for character backwards doing your own search for newlines complete your line.

Comment: Is this really what you want? Decades of devs have been content with `tail`, which lets you read the last n lines of a log, in their original order.

Comment: Colonel Panic - I know I could trap the output of tail, is it still considered OK to use the output of an external process though for something that may be called repeatedly?

Comment: As stated by @Someprogrammerdude , you can very easily do so by buffering the file in memory. It can be done very simply too, in a `while(1) {...}` loop that breaks at EOF.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I recommend a more portable (hopefully) way of file size determination since `fseek(binaryStream, offset, SEEK_END)` is not guaranteed to work. See the code below.

I believe that files should be at least minimally buffered at the kernel level (e.g. buffering at least one block per file by default), so seeks should not incur significant amount of extra I/O and should only advance the file position internally. If the default buffering is not satisfactory, you may try to use `setvbuf()` to speed up the I/O.

```
#include <limits.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

/* File must be open with 'b' in the mode parameter to fopen() */
long fsize(FILE* binaryStream)
{
  long ofs, ofs2;
  int result;

  if (fseek(binaryStream, 0, SEEK_SET) != 0 ||
      fgetc(binaryStream) == EOF)
    return 0;

  ofs = 1;

  while ((result = fseek(binaryStream, ofs, SEEK_SET)) == 0 &&
         (result = (fgetc(binaryStream) == EOF)) == 0 &&
         ofs <= LONG_MAX / 4 + 1)
    ofs *= 2;

  /* If the last seek failed, back up to the last successfully seekable offset */
  if (result != 0)
    ofs /= 2;

  for (ofs2 = ofs / 2; ofs2 != 0; ofs2 /= 2)
    if (fseek(binaryStream, ofs + ofs2, SEEK_SET) == 0 &&
        fgetc(binaryStream) != EOF)
      ofs += ofs2;

  /* Return -1 for files longer than LONG_MAX */
  if (ofs == LONG_MAX)
    return -1;

  return ofs + 1;
}

/* File must be open with 'b' in the mode parameter to fopen() */
/* Set file position to size of file before reading last line of file */
char* fgetsr(char* buf, int n, FILE* binaryStream)
{
  long fpos;
  int cpos;
  int first = 1;

  if (n <= 1 || (fpos = ftell(binaryStream)) == -1 || fpos == 0)
    return NULL;

  cpos = n - 1;
  buf[cpos] = '\0';

  for (;;)
  {
    int c;

    if (fseek(binaryStream, --fpos, SEEK_SET) != 0 ||
        (c = fgetc(binaryStream)) == EOF)
      return NULL;

    if (c == '\n' && first == 0) /* accept at most one '\n' */
      break;
    first = 0;

    if (c != '\r') /* ignore DOS/Windows '\r' */
    {
      unsigned char ch = c;
      if (cpos == 0)
      {
        memmove(buf + 1, buf, n - 2);
        ++cpos;
      }
      memcpy(buf + --cpos, &ch, 1);
    }

    if (fpos == 0)
    {
      fseek(binaryStream, 0, SEEK_SET);
      break;
    }
  }

  memmove(buf, buf + cpos, n - cpos);

  return buf;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  FILE* f;
  long sz;

  if (argc < 2)
  {
    printf("filename parameter required\n");
    return -1;
  }

  if ((f = fopen(argv[1], "rb")) == NULL)
  {
    printf("failed to open file \'%s\'\n", argv[1]);
    return -1;
  }

  sz = fsize(f);
//  printf("file size: %ld\n", sz);

  if (sz > 0)
  {
    char buf[256];
    fseek(f, sz, SEEK_SET);
    while (fgetsr(buf, sizeof(buf), f) != NULL)
      printf("%s", buf);
  }

  fclose(f);
  return 0;
}
```

I've only tested this on windows with 2 different compilers.

Comment: Thanks for that, it works really well (I could never have come up with that myself, twists my brain around alot!).

Comment: No prob. I've fixed a small bug so it can now handle properly cases where the last line does not end with `'\n'` (originally it would be concatenated with the previous line, if any).

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze, does it need free buf at last?

Comment: @scorpiozj What buffer? Is there malloc(), calloc() or realloc() in the code?

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze,got it. I just saw "copy" in memcpy(http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/memcpy.3.html) and still was in a way of objc thinking.

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze Nice code!  Just wondering why you didn't employ a stat of some kind to obtain the file size.  Did you want to remain OS agnostic?

Comment: @Jiminion Yes..

Answer (score 11):

You could just pipe the input through the program `tac`, which is like `cat` but backwards!

http://linux.die.net/man/1/tac

Comment: You can certainly find the source code for `tac` somewhere on t'internet. For example here:
http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/tree/src/tac.c

Answer (score 4):

There are quite a few ways you could do this, but reading a byte at a time is definitely one of poorer choices.

Reading the last, say, 4KB and then walking back up from the last character to the previous newline would be my choice.

Another option is to `mmap` the file, and just pretend that the file is a lump of memory, and scan backwards in that. [You can tell `mmap` you are reading backwards too, to make it prefetch data for you].

If the file is VERY large (several gigabytes), you may want to only use a small portion of the file in `mmap`.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try 'mmaping' it

Answer (score 1):

If you want to learn how to do it, here's a Debian/Ubuntu example (for other like RPM based distros, adapt as needed):

```
~$ which tac
/usr/bin/tac
~$ dpkg -S /usr/bin/tac
coreutils: /usr/bin/tac
~$ mkdir srcs
~$ cd srcs
~/srcs$ apt-get source coreutils
```

(clip apt-get output)

```
~/srcs$ ls
coreutils-8.13  coreutils_8.13-3.2ubuntu2.1.diff.gz  coreutils_8.13-3.2ubuntu2.1.dsc  coreutils_8.13.orig.tar.gz
~/srcs$ cd coreutils-8.13/
~/srcs/coreutils-8.13$ find . -name tac.c
./src/tac.c
~/srcs/coreutils-8.13$ less src/tac.c
```

That's not too long, a bit over 600 lines, and while it packs some advanced features, and uses functions from other sources, the reverse line buffering implementation seems to be in that `tac.c` source file.

Answer (score 0):

FSEEKing for every byte sounds PAINFULLY slow.

If you've got the memory, just read the entire file into memory and either reverse it or scan it backwards.

Another option would be Windows memory mapped files.

Comment: memory mapped files are not a windows-specific feature :)